# in php, what will happen if CURLOPT_CAPATH is not set when CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to true

Tags: php, curl

The problem is about using curl in PHP.
Some other answers said that curl will reject any ssl connection, however, I can send https requests as normal.
curl.cainfo in php.ini is not set.
Will curl use system default ca bundle when CURLOPT_CAPATH is not set?

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST is set to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO

This option is by default set to the system path where 
libcurl's cacert bundle is assumed to be stored, as 
established at build time.
```

So, if your system stores the cacert bundle in the default location, which is likely /etc/ssl/certs/, then it should find it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use `CURLOPT_CAPATH` Like below.

> You have to give path of your `SSL` Certificate in this line `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem");`

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem");
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$buffer_decode = json_decode($buffer);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```